# How do I get negative lives?

Tags: b3313

While playing the "abandoned" v0.9 of B3313, a romhack of Super Mario 64, I walked through a door in a red room that sent me to the castle lobby with M1 lives, indicating [a negative number of lives](https://themushroomkingdom.net/bugs/128). It made me near immune from getting a game over, as dying simply made the M counter increase. My lives reset to normal after restarting the game.

How did I end up with negative lives? Can I get negative lives again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certain doors and pipes in B3313 have warps that take away a life. You can get negative lives by entering one of these warps when you have 0 lives. The easiest method for negative lives I found in v0.9 and v1.0 was a repeatable death warp in Plexal Lobby.

1. Start at Castle Grounds:
2. Enter double front doors to either [Beta Lobby A](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Lobby_A) (Left Door) or [Beta Lobby E](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Lobby_E) (Right door)

   - Lobby A and E look near identical, but count as separate areas.
3. Enter double doors at the top and fall through trapdoor to [Beta Lobby B](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Lobby_B). (Requires at least one red star, otherwise warps to bowser).
4. Head through one of the two middle doors on the first floor then enter double doors down the hall for [Plexal Lobby](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Plexal_Lobby).
5. In the room with a chandelier, jump down to first floor then turn around.
6. Go straight down hallway through double key doors.
7. Head straight past boos through double key doors.
8. Enter the pair of doors on either the right or left side to death warp to the chandelier room.
9. Repeat steps 6 to 8 until you have negative lives.

I have also found a few other death warps I've found in v0.9 that can give negative lives. In the Plexal Lobby, if you enter a door on the bottom floor with a 1 on it, there's a death warp pipe to Vanilla Lobby. I've also been death warped by Big Boo cages, and the wiki lists a death warp in [Dead Village](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Dead_Village).